# ZF2 Float input for price field for german website

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

I need an input field for a price field for a german website. Therefore I added a `NumberFormat` filter and the `IsFloat` validator. The entered price (e.g. `7,5`) gets stored correct to the database double field in the format `7.5`. But now the problem is, if I wan't to edit the field, it gets populated in the format `7.5` to the user, which he can't save, because it's not a german format. So he has to replace the `"."` with a `","`.

Is there a way, to populate the number with a `","` instead of the `"."`?

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
    return [
        'price' => [
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'NumberFormat',
                    'options' => [
                        'locale' => 'de_DE'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'IsFloat',
                    'options' => [
                        'locale' => 'de_DE'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: You should use int to manage price so you don't have to bother with floats. This is the way it's done in most business i've seen.
For example 17€93 would be (int)1793.
Btw it's handle this way in supermarket when you pay with your creditcard

Comment: Hmm good hint. Does that mean, that 17€ would be 1700?

Comment: Exactly, then you just have to build a function to display your currency, but that souldn't be too hard

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a `ViewHelper` that renders the float with a `,` instead of a `.`. Changing the storage of the data in the database and internally handling floats with a `,` separator seems not the right way to go and will definitely cause issues.

There is even an **[inbuilt currency formatter](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.i18n.view.helpers.html#currencyformat-helper)** view helper in **ZF2** that you can use.

For your German currency notation it will be as simple as:

```
echo $this->currencyFormat(1234.56, 'EUR', null, 'de_DE');
```